# How to get the dimensions of the rights notices on Google Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add my own anchors/links (or custom controls, perhaps) on the bottom of the Google Maps canvas.  According to [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) (please see section 8.5 *Proprietary Rights Notices*), developers are not supposed to **block** any proprietary rights notices, hence I have to utilize the space between the two **<DIV></DIV>**'s on the **bottom right** as well as the other on the **bottom left** corners!
[image]

Is there any way to calculate or to measure the dimensions (mainly widths) of the **rights notices** (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features)?

I am looking for solid, API-oriented solutions; e.g, not just parsing the generated DOM elements by **classes** and/or **id**'s since they are prone to be changed.

Thanx in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1):

I think maps will ensure right notices are not overlapped when you place custom control using `map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM].push(control)` method. But I didn't check it.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response! Actually I'm trying to put my own "about, privacy, TOS anchors/links" right next to the Google logo (aligned to the right side of it). I have also tried google.maps.ControlPosition.* but the positions are pre-defined which are not where I want them to be. :)